# Flutter Form state stuck in FormBlocSuccess using flutter_form_bloc

Tags: flutter

After fields on Settings screen are saved, my form reports FormBlocSuccess and returns to the previous screen. After the Settings screen is entered again, the state of the form remains as FormBlocSuccess and the submit button is disabled. I want the bloc to be in a state that allows the form to enable the submit button again - without recreating the FormBloc. How is that possible?

Here is the page snippet

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<SettingsFormBloc>(
      create: (context) => BlocProvider.of<SettingsFormBloc>(context),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          SettingsFormBloc formBloc = BlocProvider.of<SettingsFormBloc>(context);
          print("FormBloc = ${formBloc.state}");
          if (formBloc.state is FormBlocSuccess) {
            print("SUCCESS!");
            formBloc.emitLoaded();
          }
          return _settingsScreen(context, formBloc);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is the Bloc code that updates the state:

```
void onSubmitting() async {
    emitSuccess(canSubmitAgain: true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by calling BlocBuilder rather than BlocProvider. There were a number of other changes as well but that is the main gist of it.